# SQL Table Variables - adding constraint that checks for existence of matching row set

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists, check-constraints, table-variable

*Updating with pmbAustin's suggestion*

pmbAustin, thanks. I think that will work. I've created a function "dbo.CK_WinteamSportExists" that returns a 0 or 1. However I'm now getting a baffling error message. When I tested my solution I get the following:

```
create table #check
(
SportID int
,WinTeamID int
,LoseTeamID int
,check 
(
(dbo.CK_WinteamSportExists (WinTeamID , SportID) = 1)
)
)
```

Error Message:
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.CK_WinteamSportExists", or the name is ambiguous.

I tried using a fully qualified name "mydatabase.dbo.CK_WinteamSportExists", no dice.
It appears that I've got the syntax wrong in the check, but for the life of me I can't find the error.

*Original Question*
I am trying to enforce referential integrity on a table variable.  I'm working in SQL Server 2012.

```
declare @GameID_Table table (
GameID int
,SportID int
,WinTeamID int
,LoseTeamID int
)
```

Combinations of WinTeamID/SportID and LoseTeamID/SportID in @GameID_Table must be constrained by the existence of a matching row in a separate table Link_TeamSport defined as:

```
create table Link_TeamSport
(
TeamID int,
SportID int
primary key (TeamID, SportID)
)
```

Normally I'd do this with a composite foreign key, however these are not allowed in table variables.
I also tried creating user-defined functions that check for the existence of a matching row in Link_TeamSport, but UDFs are not allowed in table variables either.

Here is an example of working code that illustrates my constraint condition.  The code below returns a result of 1 if a matching row is found and 0 if not. However, I cannot figure out how to incorporate this concept into the check constraint within @GameID_Table.

```
declare @winteam int
declare @sportid int
set @winteam = 1001
set @sportid = 4001

select count(*) from 
(
select lts.TeamID, lts.sportid from Link_TeamSport lts
where 
(@winteam = lts.TeamID and @sportid = lts.sportid)
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a #TempTable instead.  @TableVariables have a lot of restrictions that #TempTables don't, and also don't perform as well if you're going to have more than just a few rows in them.